# [Error: The file “IMG-7018.mov” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.]

Tags: javascript, react-native, api, video, upload

## **I am trying to uploading a video in IOS through RNFS then it's throwing this error

## **

[image]

**Upload video from device**

```html
  const RemoveExist = data => {
    const filePath = data?.uri.split('///').pop(); // removes leading file:///

    console.log(data);
    RNFS.exists(filePath).then(status => {
      if (status) {
        console.log('Yay! File exists');
        // setVideo(data);
        RNFS.unlink(filePath).then(() => console.log('FIrLE DELETED'));
      } else {
        console.log('File not exists');
        // setVideo(data);
      }
    });
  };
  const SelectVideo = () => {
    launchImageLibrary({mediaType: 'video', videoQuality: 'low'}, response => {
      console.log(response.assets[0]);
      if (!response.didCancel) {
        // setVideo('');
        setVideo(response.assets[0]);
        console.log('file setted!!', response.assets[0]?.uri);
        setTimeout(() => {
          RemoveExist(response.assets[0]);
        }, 2000);
      }
    });
  };
```

**Upload video from device to database**

```
  const urlComponents = video?.uri.split('/');
        const fileNameAndExtension = urlComponents[urlComponents.length - 1];
        const destPath = `${RNFS.TemporaryDirectoryPath}/${fileNameAndExtension}`;
        await RNFS.copyFile(video?.uri, destPath);

        console.log('file://' + destPath);
        body.append('video', {
          name: 'video.mp4',
          uri: 'file://' + destPath,
          type: video.type,
        });
```

1. I'll try to store `file in new state`.
2. I'll try to clear `RNFS cache` before & after choosing file
3. I'll try to clean `temp` in RNFS

Comment: The error says that the file does not exist, however, based on the code you shared it is not clear whether you make sure the file is there or not. Please share all relevant code including where you store the file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.